# How to close all accordions in Magento2 admin product detail by default

Tags: bundle, admin, accordion, magento2

when I open a product detail page (for example of a bundle product) in Magento2 1 accordion is always open, in this case the one of the bundle items. Even if I close it and save the product, it's open again after the reload. As I often need to change product details below this accordion It would be great to have it closed by default. So far I did not find the right place to override this setting in the code.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Jonas

Comment: Great question, We need to know how to fix this. The Magento 2 devs need to fix this along with everything else that is not user friendly in the Magento 2 admin.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Overriding ( as described below ) the class 
***Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePane*** for your requirement.

I assume you will create a custom module name "**Vendor_Module**" to do this customization tasks

**step 1)** Create **di.xml** under

***/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/***

File : **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" 
                type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" />
</config>
```

**step 2:** Create **BundlePanel.php** under

***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/***

File : **BundlePanel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class BundlePanel extends \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = parent::modifyMeta($meta);
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CODE_BUNDLE_DATA, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $path,
            $meta,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataScope' => '',
                            'opened' => false,
                            'sortOrder' => $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                $meta,
                                static::GROUP_CONTENT,
                                static::SORT_ORDER
                            )
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
           );
        return $meta;
    }


}
```

**step 3:** Run di compile  commnad

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**step 4:** clean your Magento cache

========================================================

**Please Note:**

To **Show/hide** the Bundle Items tab, Please change **$meta** array  key "**opened**" valye to **true/false** in the Overriding class file **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel.php** as follows :

'**opened**' => **false**,

========================================================